# should Visual Studio 2015 (devenv.exe + vshub) take 500kb+ of memory and 100% of two cores just to start up?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Is this standard behavior for Visual Studio 2015?

I just upgraded from VS2013 to VS2015, and the new Visual Studio is using so many resources that my system will freeze on a regular basis.  Starting up the IDE causes my CPU to peg for over a minute (two cores of a 2.66Ghz intel i7 processor), with devenv.exe and up to four instances of VsHub.exe running.

Once the IDE is up and running, resource monitor often shows multiple versions of Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe running, and these seem to take on more memory over time, almost like they have a memory leak?

Have others seen this as well? I'm asking because I am trying to decide if this is a solvable issue, or if I need to go back to VS2013 to get work done.

Below is a screenshot of my system shortly after my project opens in the IDE.
[image]

... and now over 1GB of memory while debugging an iis application:
[image]

Comment: Not sure this is definitive but my versions of those processes don't seem to be leaking (30MB after running all day). Startup does tend to be expensive though I've never experienced what you describe (and I routinely start up 3, 4 instances after a reboot right away)

Comment: VS2015 takes a lot of toll on my system as well. I was too appalled to use it anymore and ran away all the way under the shelter of VS2010. Now life is calm!